# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation 'caves' does not exist

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I've ran into a problem in which I'm not sure how to get out of this. Working on creating a rails view, and after populating my view and editing my controller, i've ran into an error that states `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation 'caves'  does not exist`

Looking into what I did, I realized that I created my model as `cafe` but when I populated my schema tables, I accidentally created a table called `caves` instead of `cafes`.

Here's what I did to try to resolve this.

1. I first tried creating a migration to just rename the table from `caves` to `cafes` -- still ran into the same error
2. I then tried deleting the schema table all together and creating a new one all together called `cafe` - still ran into the same error
3. I then tried dropping my database all together, thinking if I just wiped the whole thing and started over (i just started on this rails project). I ran `rake db:reset` only to come into a new error telling me `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  database "cafe_database" is being accessed by other users`
4. By this point, I tried restarted my postgress and ran `sudo service postgresql restart`....but my machine doesn't recognize `service`

Does anybody have an idea what I can do to figure this problem out? I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: First off, make sure no other session to DB is open. Then try what @puneet mentioned.

Comment: how do you check to see if there are no other sessions to the DB that are open? Is that done by running `ps -aef | grep rails` and killing off any xtra pids?

Comment: Manually check all `rails c`, `rails s`, command line psql sessions etc and close them. If you still face the issue, checkout https://www.devopsderek.com/blog/2012/11/13/list-and-disconnect-postgresql-db-sessions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below steps:

```
1. rake db:drop
2. rake db:create
3. rake db:migrate
```

Comment: This will completely wipe the database and start from scratch.  If you are in a development environment with only test data this is fine. but do not do this in a live environment as you will lose all the data.